# Update view count of a question automatically

Tags: feature-request

When reading a new question the comments and answers update automatically without having to reload the page. The only thing that doesn't update is the view count of the question.

I know this is a pretty minor thing. Would be nice to have the view count update automatically though.

Comment: Really?  As far as I can tell, the comments update when you post a comment, the votes update when you vote, the answers update when you post an answer, the views update when you view it again, i.e. reload the page.

Comment: The answers, comments and edits update automatically without reloading the page for me on Safari.

Comment: Answers offer click to load because it makes sense to see new ones.  Comments offer click to load because it helps with active questions, and it also helps to see if the OP has answered a clarifying question, or if someone has asked a clarifying question.  Questions offer click to load because it helps to know if the OP has edited their question.  View counts don't offer click to load because it doesn't add anything substantial to the question.  It's only there to serve as a marker of how popular the question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't get your hopes up -- even though it would be fun to watch the counts go up live, this won't happen. The view counts are [infrequently updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80857/230261) and are also [cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how), and for good reason. It's just too much load to have them be updated live (note there are *far* more views per time than there are votes or anything else), for too little real benefit.